# Is it possible to communicate with Rainbow bridge via API from a smart contract from NEAR?

Tags: aurora-evm, rainbow-bridge

Is it possible to communicate with Rainbow bridge via API from a smart contract from NEAR? Let's say I want to take NEAR, send it to a smart contract in NEAR blockchain. Then I want this smart contract to automatically send it through the bridge to Aurora, send to some contract, after some time, get money back  and bridge back and send to the original user's wallet on NEAR

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only NEP-141 tokens can be sent from NEAR to Aurora and back so what you mentioned would be possible with wNEAR.

General asynchronous communication between NEAR and Aurora is being developed. Discussions are underway  about adding native NEAR support inside of Aurora: https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-bridge/discussions/642.